# How can one conclude that $f$ is differentiable?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> How can one conclude that $f$ is differentiable ?

If $f:\mathbb R\to S^1=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|=1\} $ is continuous and such that $f(a+b)=f(a)f(b)$

then the formula holds

$\displaystyle f(x)\int_0^af(t)dt=\int_0^af(x+t)dt=\int_0^{a+x}f(t)dt-\int_0^xf(t)dt$

what does it mean now if the integral on the left does not vanish then $f'(x)$ exists since the integral of a continuous function is differentiable or what ?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: If the integral on the left vanishes then the function is identical zero, so $f'(x)$ exists again.